# Another way to improve the SQL Query to avoid union?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

User can search by Postcode (eg: L14, L15, L16) or Location from a textbox.

If user type in "Liverpool", it will find all the shops that are located in "Liverpool".  If User type in the postcode (Eg: L15), it will search all the shops that do delivery in  L15 postcode zone.

See the Tables below:

```
mysql> select * from shops;
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
| id | name     | location  | postcode |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |
|  2 | Shop Two | Liverpool | L16      |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+
```

-

```
mysql> select * from shops_delivery_area;
+------------------+---------+----------+---------------+
| delivery_area_id | shop_id | postcode | delivery_cost |
+------------------+---------+----------+---------------+
|                1 |       1 | L10      |          1.50 |
|                2 |       1 | L11      |          0.00 |
|                3 |       1 | L12      |          1.00 |
|                4 |       1 | L13      |          1.00 |
|                5 |       2 | L10      |          2.50 |
|                6 |       2 | L16      |          0.00 |
|                7 |       2 | L28      |          0.00 |
+------------------+---------+----------+---------------+
```

**SQL Query:**

```
SELECT U.* FROM 
   ((SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, DA.delivery_cost, DA.postcode AS AreaPostcode FROM shops
             JOIN shops_delivery_area as DA on (DA.shop_id = shops.id)
   WHERE DA.postcode = "Liverpool")
  UNION
   (SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, DA.delivery_cost, DA.postcode AS AreaPostcode FROM shops
             JOIN shops_delivery_area as DA on  
                              (DA.shop_id = shops.id AND
                              DA.postcode = shops.postcode)
   WHERE shops.location = "Liverpool")) as U
```

-

**Result -  by Location (Liverpool):**

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
| id | name     | location  | postcode | delivery_cost | AreaPostcode |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |          1.50 | L10          |
|  2 | Shop Two | Liverpool | L16      |          0.00 | L16          |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

**Result - by Postcode (L12):**

```
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
| id | name     | location  | postcode | delivery_cost | AreaPostcode |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 | Shop One | Liverpool | L10      |          1.00 | L12          |
+----+----------+-----------+----------+---------------+--------------+
```

It appear to be working correctly... 
Is there other way to improve the SQL query shorter to avoid `union` or something?

Comment: What rationale do you have for avoiding `UNION`? p.s. I think you can remove the `DISTINCT` keywords because `UNION` is short for `UNION DISTINCT`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whatever you choose, be aware that short code is not always optimal code.  In many cases, where you have sufficiently divergent logic, unioning the results really is the most optimal (and sometimes most clean, programatically) option.

That said, the following OR in the WHERE clause seems to cover both your cases...

```
SELECT DISTINCT
  shops.*,
  DA.delivery_cost,
  DA.postcode AS AreaPostcode
FROM
  shops
INNER JOIN
  shops_delivery_area as DA
    ON (DA.shop_id = shops.id)
WHERE
  (DA.postcode = "Liverpool")
OR
  (DA.postcode = shops.postcode AND shops.location = "Liverpool")
```

Comment: Thanks! So which would be better option in performance wise? Stick with Union or `OR` in the WHERE clause

Comment: I've just done performance testing.. It appear using `Union` is faster.

Comment: @user791022 sayd `I've just done performance testing.. It appear using Union is faster.` **I told you so.**  what is faster two index hits into the middle of a table or a scan of the entire table?  when you apply "application" thinking (reduce redundant code, etc) to SQL you run into performance problems.

Comment: @KM. - While I agree with you on the technical details, I also only learned this lesson by being proven wrong.  As my knowledge of SQL grew, I looked for innovative ways to shorten code.  That's when I discovered execution plans and how they relate (or not) to my understanding of SQL.  I think it's good the OP is constantly searching for *better*.  I'm even glad the OP is challenging what others say, and resolving imperical evidence against theories and what others say.

Answer (score 1):

Since all tables and selected columns are the same, you can simply do this:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, DA.delivery_cost, DA.postcode AS AreaPostcode FROM shops
             JOIN shops_delivery_area as DA on DA.shop_id = shops.id
   WHERE (DA.postcode = "Liverpool")
      OR (DA.postcode = shops.postcode AND shops.location = "Liverpool")
```

Like you said in Diego's answer, the conditions are a litle different! So, you compensate that difference in the `WHERE clause`.

Answer (score 0):

What am I missing? 
Why cant you do

```
 WHERE DA.postcode = "Liverpool" or shops.location = "Liverpool"
```

Comment: That wouldn't work properly, otherwise you will get many rows of same shops name. Take a look at `JOIN`'s carefully.

Comment: using an `OR` can kill performance depending on how the indexes are being used.   I'll usually split a query into a `UNION` like this to avoid an `OR` and get the substantial performance gain of using an an index in each part of the `UNION`.

Comment: @Diego, you are missing one restriction when it is `shops.location = "Liverpool"`.

Comment: just add another constraint on the location test to avoid that like DA.postcode = shops.postcode

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT shops.*, 
       DA.delivery_cost, 
       DA.postcode 
FROM shops 
       JOIN shops_delivery_area as DA on DA.shop_id = shops.id
WHERE DA.postcode = "Liverpool" 
      OR (location = "Liverpool" and DA.postcode = shops.postcode)
```